# Conditional variance $\text{Var}(Y \mid X, Z)$ for partitioned multivariate Gaussian vector

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have an upcoming *Regression Models* exam and I am currently doing an exercise. The point of the exercise is to find a conditional variance $\operatorname{Var}(Y | X, Z)$.

Given:

- A random vector $X = (Y, X, Z)$ is Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu = (1, 2, 4)^T$ and covariance matrix:

$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1\\
3 & 5 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$$

The formula that I use is the following:

$\operatorname{Var}(Y | X) = E[(y - \mu(x))^2 | X) = \operatorname{Var}(Y) - \operatorname{Cov}(Y, X)\operatorname{Cov}(X, X)^{-1}\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$

The problem: I **do not understand** what to do when there's more than one variable in the condition.

Comment: You may want to consider replacing the regression tags with those for conditional probability and conditional expectation: the motivation of the problem may be that of the former, but the subject of the problem seems more in line with the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The part that considers me as well is the mean vector $\mu$. You say that $$\mu =\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_a \\
\mu_b \end{pmatrix}$$ By looking at your explanation, I see that $\mu_a = Y = 1$. Is it that $\mu_b = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}^T $?

Answer (score 2):

The formula you are using is a special case of:

> Let the column vector $X:=(X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n)^T$ have multivariate Gaussian distribution. Partition $X$ into disjoint subvectors $X_a$ and $X_b$:
> $$
> X = \left(\begin{matrix}X_a\\X_b\end{matrix}\right)
> $$
> and correspondingly partition the mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of $X$:
> $$
> \mu = \left(\begin{matrix}\mu_a\\ \mu_b\end{matrix}\right);\qquad
> \Sigma=\left(\begin{matrix}\Sigma_{a,a}&\Sigma_{a,b}\\\Sigma_{b,a}&\Sigma_{b,b}\end{matrix}\right)$$
> Then
> $$E(X_a\mid X_b)=\mu_a + C(X_b - \mu_b)\tag1$$ and
> $$\operatorname{Var}(X_a\mid X_b)=\Sigma_{a,a}-C\Sigma_{b,a}\tag2$$
> where $C:=\Sigma_{a,b}\Sigma_{b,b}^{-1}$.

In your situation you have $n=3$ with $X_a$ being a (univariate) random variable, and $X_b$ being a bivariate vector. So to compute the conditional variance you just partition the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ that you've been handed into four submatrices, and plug the relevant pieces into (2).

---

ADDED:
In more detail, $X_a=Y$ and $X_b=(X,Z)^T$ so your covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is partitioned into
$$\Sigma=\left(\begin{matrix}\Sigma_{a,a}&\Sigma_{a,b}\\\Sigma_{b,a}&\Sigma_{b,b}\end{matrix}\right)
=\left(
\begin{array}{c|cc}
2&3&1\\
\hline
3&5&2\\
1&2&6
\end{array}
\right).$$ Now read off the submatrices: $$\Sigma_{a,a}=2,\qquad
\Sigma_{a,b}=\left(\begin{matrix}3&1\end{matrix}\right),\qquad
\Sigma_{b,a}=\left(\begin{matrix}3\\1\end{matrix}\right),\qquad
\Sigma_{b,b}=\left(\begin{matrix} 5&2\\2&6\end{matrix}\right).$$
Plug into (2):
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X,Z)=
2 - \left(\begin{matrix}3&1\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 5&2\\2&6\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{matrix}3\\1\end{matrix}\right).
$$
I leave it to you to perform the matrix operations.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite get it. Perhaps you can show me a tad bit more?

Comment: @RokasR I have added a tad more detail.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my last comment? 

P.S. thanks for the clarification about this one. It helped a lot.

Comment: Yes, $\mu_a=E(Y)=1$ and $\mu_b=E(X,Z)^T=(2,4)^T$.